# Executing Jmeter script in Ubuntu,facing error

Tags: java, linux, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

```
: not found: ./jmeter:
: not found7: ./jmeter:
: not found4: ./jmeter:
: not found8: ./jmeter:
./jmeter: 85: ./jmeter: Syntax error: "elif" unexpected (expecting "then")
```

Executing command from bin folder.

My Unix command is:

```
$ ./jmeter -n -t ./JMX/Generate_Dashboard.jmx \
      -l ./JMX/Generate_Dashboard.jtl -e -o ./JMX/Generate_Report
```

Comment: Where is the script? How did you download jmeter?

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 85 of your .jmx script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Running JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running), you need to execute from bin folder under jmeter main folder:

> To run JMeter, run the jmeter.bat (for Windows) or jmeter (for Unix) file. These files are found in the bin directory.